# REGEX Positive lookbehind OR lookahead?

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I want to make a regex that matches a word ONLY if there are a certain number of characters are ahead OR behind it. Doesn't matter what the characters are.

This is what i have so far. `(?<=.{6})\bfoo\b(?=.{6})`

This seems to only match if there are 6+ characters behind "foo", but I want to make it so it will also match if there are 6 characters ahead as well. Sot it should be able to match both of the following examples:

this is a foo

foo this is

But it shouldn't match "foo"

Nvm I found out that this works: `(?<=.{6})\bfoo\b|\bfoo\b(?=.{6})`
I guess my question now is there a "cleaner" way of formatting it so I don't have to write "foo" twice?

Comment: Why not use capture group like `.{0,6}\b(foo)\b(?=.{0,6})`

Comment: Did my answer below help?

Comment: No it didn't help...it says the "group conditional" is not supported.

Comment: @Lemons That means you should add the programming language and the regex library details to the question. When a question is tagged with `regex`, it defaults to PCRE regex  here (at least, most people assume that, as the default regex flavor used at regex101.com (commonly used to test regexps) is PCRE).

Answer (score 0):

You can use two techniques here:

1. Make use of a non-capturing group with two alternatives after matching `foo`, one will require any six chars after `foo` and another will require them before `foo`:

```php
\bfoo\b(?:(?=.{6})|(?<=.{6}foo))
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/iWh6la/2). *Details*:

- `\bfoo\b` - matches a whole word `foo`
- `(?:` - start of a non-capturing group:

  - `(?=.{6})` - a positive lookahead that requires any six chars other than line break chars to occur immediately to the right of the current location (i.e. right after `foo`)
  - `|` - or
  - `(?<=.{6}foo)` - a positive lookbehind that requires any six chars other than line break chars and then `foo` (we need to match it, too, as the regex index is currenely after `foo`) immediately to the left of the current location
- `)` - end of the group.

2. Utilize a [conditional construct](https://www.regular-expressions.info/conditional.html) and a lookbehind with an alternation:

```php
(?<=(.{6})|)\bfoo\b(?(1)|(?=.{6}))
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/iWh6la/1). *Details*:

- `(?<=(.{6})|)` - a positive lookbehind that matches a location immediately preceded with any six char other than line break chars, or an empty string
- `\bfoo\b` - a whole word `foo`
- `(?(1)|(?=.{6}))` - a conditional construct that matches an empty string if Group 1 matched, else, the `(?=.{6})` requires any six chars other than line break chars to occur immediately to the right of the `foo` word.